# How to alternatively print 2 different strings while using end=''?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print these two strings alternatively, but cannot find a way around it without using end=''. I am trying to use as little strings as possible, my goal is to use only 2 strings.

```
num_of_stars = int(input("How many stars would you like on each line?: 
"))
lines1 = 0
lines2 = 0
alternator = 0
def line1(num_of_stars):
    for i in range(num_of_stars):
        print("*", end=' ')
def line2(num_of_stars):
    for i in range(num_of_stars):
        print(" *", end='')
while lines1 <= 4 and lines2 <= 4:
    if alternator == 0:
        line1(num_of_stars)
        lines1 += 1
        alternator = 1
    elif alternator == 1:
        line2(num_of_stars)
        lines2 += 1
        alternator = 0
```

My results have just been this: * * * * * *  * * * * * ** * * * * *  * * * * * ** * * * * *  * * * * * ** * * * * *  * * * * * ** * * * * *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want.
But you probably don't want to use the `print( ... , end=...)` technique
shown in your code.

It would be much simpler to assign

```
stars = ['*'] * num_of_stars
line = ' '.join(stars)
```

and then

```
for i in range(4):
    indent = ' '[:i % 2]
    print(indent + line)
```

The `indent` string will be empty or a blank,
according to whether i is even or odd.

Comment: Thank you so much! If it's not too much to ask, could you please walk me through the indent variable? I'm having trouble understanding how it did what it did. Sorry if its obvious, I'm a beginner.

Comment: `i` will take on the values [0, 1, 2, 3]. Let's evaluate `i` modulo 2 for each of them. The values are even, odd, even, odd, so we get [0, 1, 0, 1]. Now consider a string constant that is a single blank. If we take zero characters from it, we get nothing, we get empty string. OTOH if our slice takes one character from it we get a blank. So `indent` is always nothing, or a blank. It conveniently lets us display a bunch of stars flush with left margin, or offset by one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the end of the line 2 function is just a blank space, which explains why there are groups of 2 stars grouped together at intervals.
Try this:

```
num_of_stars = int(input("How many stars would you like on each line?: "))
lines1 = 0
lines2 = 0
alternator = 0
def line1(num_of_stars):
    for i in range(num_of_stars):
        print("*", end="")
    print("\n")
def line2(num_of_stars):
    for i in range(num_of_stars):
        print("*", end="")
    print("\n")
while lines1 <= 4 and lines2 <= 4:
    if alternator == 0:
        line1(num_of_stars)
        lines1 += 1
        alternator = 1
    elif alternator == 1:
        line2(num_of_stars)
        lines2 += 1
        alternator = 0
```